# how to install hologram python SDK onto raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I am following this tutorial (https://support.hologram.io/hc/en-us/articles/360035697273-Get-started-with-the-Hologram-Nova)

In this tutorial, and many others, it says you can simply install the hologram SDK by doing:

```
curl -L hologram.io/python-install | bash
```

Then to run a command you do:

```
sudo hologram send "Hello World"
```

But I get the error `sudo: hologram: command not found`

I have tried using a fresh OS install (Raspian Buster version 10)
I have tried to also do `sudo apt-get update` before I install hologram.

What else can I do here?

Here is the output from the terminal when I run `curl -L hologram.io/python-update| bash`

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   166  100   166    0     0   1456      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1456
100   166  100   166    0     0    526      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   526
100   166  100   166    0     0    281      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1286
100  4329  100  4329    0     0   5063      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5063
Linux system detected
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease                                                        
Hit:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease                                                     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
bash: line 111: hologram: command not found
python3 is already installed.
ps is already installed.
kill is already installed.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpython3.7-dev is already the newest version (3.7.3-2+deb10u2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  alsa-base gconf-service gconf2-common gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-plugins-base libboost-system1.62.0 libboost-thread1.62.0 libdrm-etnaviv1 libgconf-2-4
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libllvm6.0 libmicrodns0 libreoffice-gtk2 libva-wayland2 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util7
  libxfconf-0-2 lxplug-volume pimixer point-rpi python3-pyperclip xfconf
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ip is already installed.
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting hologram-python
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/hologram-python/hologram_python-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyusb~=1.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from hologram-python) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyroute2==0.5.* in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from hologram-python) (0.5.14)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-sdk-auth~=0.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from hologram-python) (0.3.0)
Collecting requests~=2.22.0 (from hologram-python)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyserial~=3.4.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from hologram-python) (3.4)
Collecting mock~=3.0.5 (from hologram-python)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/d2/f94e68be6b17f46d2c353564da56e6fb89ef09faeeff3313a046cb810ca9/mock-3.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-pppd==1.0.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from hologram-python) (1.0.3)
Collecting pyudev~=0.21.0 (from hologram-python)
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/pyudev/pyudev-0.21.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psutil~=5.6.3 (from hologram-python)
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/psutil/psutil-5.6.7-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: hjson~=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from hologram-python) (3.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pycryptodome==3.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from python-sdk-auth~=0.3.0->hologram-python) (3.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests~=2.22.0->hologram-python) (2018.8.24)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests~=2.22.0->hologram-python) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests~=2.22.0->hologram-python) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests~=2.22.0->hologram-python) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from mock~=3.0.5->hologram-python) (1.12.0)
Installing collected packages: requests, mock, pyudev, psutil, hologram-python
  Found existing installation: requests 2.21.0
    Uninstalling requests-2.21.0:
      Successfully uninstalled requests-2.21.0
  Found existing installation: psutil 5.5.1
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'psutil'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Did you restart your terminal?

Comment: Yes, restarted the whole device.

Comment: I added some additional info, sorry this should have been on the original post.

Comment: Try with `python -m hologram send "hello world!"`

Comment: It seems to open a python console? It just starts a new line with `>` and allows me to type, but does not do anything.
I tried to do this in a python script by first using `import Hologram` but it returns `ModuleNotFOundError: No module named 'Hologram'`

Comment: you could try https://community.hologram.io/